# jQuery dialog() works on one page but not on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a page in which I include jQuery and jQuery UI to create a modal dialog from a div-element. This works fine. Now from another page with the same HTML markup and a reference to the same JavaScript files, I do the exact same thing and get the following error:

**Internet Explorer 8:**

> Object doesn't support this property or method

**Chrome (26.0.1410.64):**

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'dialog'

This is what the HTML looks like in both the pages:

```
<div id="dialog-message" class="ui-widget" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: none;" title="Activity Monitoring">
    <p>
        <span id="messageContainer"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

And this is the code where things go wrong on the second page. Mind that the first line gets executed correctly and that the content of 'messageContainer' is set correctly:

```
$('#messageContainer').html(message);
$('#dialog-message').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    bgiframe: true,
    draggable: false,
    height: "auto",
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
    position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
    resizable: false,
    width: 450,
    buttons: dialogButtons
});
```

These are the includes of the jQuery-files. I omitted the path partially for privacy reasons but I verified it and it works as the first line of jQuery code is succesfully executed. The third include is the reference to the file where the above JavaScript code is written:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://.../javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://.../javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://.../javascript/Utility.js"></script>
```

Am I missing or looking over something here? I cannot find out why in one page this works perfectly and in another I get the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this might be redundant but did the jquery-ui library get downloaded properly according to CDT?

Comment: What is CDT? (sorry if this is stupid :D)

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools :P

Comment: check if you do not include jquery ui twice...

Comment: Why wouldn't it be downloaded correctly if it works on one page and not on the other while the messageContainer is set correctly? :) @DavorMlinaric: post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer. Seems there was someone who edited the (SharePoint) page and added another reference to an older version of jQuery.

Comment: @abbas, because the first line uses only jQuery and not jQuery-UI

Comment: You're right, didn't think that one through.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you do not include jquery ui twice

Comment: The problem was indeed that there was a second include somewhere on the SharePoint page of an older version of jQuery. :)